# Two columns from subquery (mysql)

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

Having a table like below:

```
TB1

ID1 NAME
--- ----
1   Mark
2   Elis

TB2

ID2 ID1 DATE       VALUE
--- --- ---------- ------
10  1   2018-01-01 100,00
20  1   2019-01-01 101,00
30  2   2018-02-01 200,00
40  2   2019-02-01 201,00
```

I want the result of the two tables with the `ID` and `NAME` unique, `DATE` descending and its' value. This is what I have tried but it isn't working:

```
SELECT TB1.NAME,
       (
        SELECT 
          TB2.DATE,
          TB2.VALUE 
        FROM 
          TB2 
        WHERE 
          TB1.ID1=TB2.ID1 
        ORDER BY 
          TB2.DATE DESC 
        LIMIT 1
       ) 
       AS M_DATE,M_VALUE
       FROM 
          TB1
      WHERE 
          TB1.ID1>0
```

My expected result would be this:

```
EXPECTED RESULT
===============
NAME M_DATE     M_VALUE
---- ---------- -------
Mark 2019-01-01 101,00
Elis 2019-02-01 201,00
```

Comment: So you want a join of TB1 with TB2 on column ID1, but what row from TB2 do you want? based on highest VALUE or latest DATE?

Comment: @verhie Highest DATE but must expose the corresponding VALUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT TB1.NAME, TB2.`DATE`, TB2.VALUE
FROM TB1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID1, MAX(`DATE`) AS M_DATE 
  FROM TB2 GROUP BY ID1
) TB2_MAX ON TB1.ID1 = TB2_MAX.ID1
  INNER JOIN TB2 ON TB2_MAX.ID1 = TB2.ID1 AND TB2_MAX.M_DATE = TB2.`DATE`
WHERE TB1.ID1 > 0
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a1e7076f5507d08064f577003942578)

Comment: GREAT! Works. Thank you Sebastian.